# Como puedo validar 3 botones input empleando php

Tags: php, html, validación

Estoy trabajando sobre la bd world, el codigo es funcional hasta que trato de implementar la validacion. El formulario posee el boton Rellenar que busca las lenguas de un pais, luego el boton Buscar carga los datos referente a la lengua (si es oficial o no y el % de hablantes), estos valores cargados pueden ser modificados si se presiona el boton Aceptar, lo que quiero es que si no se ha presionado el boton Rellenar al presionar el boton Buscar o el Aceptar de un mensaje de error, y lo mismo para el boton Aceptar el cual debe indicar que primero se debe presionar el boton Buscar. el codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
 $equipo = "localhost";                                                   
 $usuario = "admin";
 $contraseña = "admin";
 $bd = "world";
 $puerto= "3306";

 $enlace = mysqli_connect($equipo, $usuario, $contraseña, $bd, $puerto);  

  if (!$enlace) {                                                        
     die("Error al conectar: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

$codPais = "";              
$oficial = "";
$porcentaje = "";
$brellenar=false;
$bbuscar=false;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Modificar Lenguaje</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>MODIFICACIÓN DE DATOS DE UNA LENGUA EN UN PAÍS</h2>

<form method="post">
    <label for="codp"><b>Código de país</b></label>
    <select name="codp">
        <?php                                                               
        $codPais = $_POST['codp'];
        $consulta1 = "SELECT Code, Name FROM country order by Code ASC";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($enlace, $consulta1);

        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {                    
            $selected = ($codPais == $fila['Code']) ? 'selected' : '';  
            echo "<option value='" . $fila['Code'] . "' " . $selected . ">" . $fila['Code'] . '-' . $fila['Name'] . "</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select><br><br>

    <label for="lang"><b>Lengua</b></label>
    <select name="lang">
        <?php                                                                       
        if (isset($_POST['accion']) && $_POST['accion'] == "Rellenar") { 
            $brellenar=true;                       
            $consulta2 = "SELECT Language FROM countrylanguage WHERE Countrycode='$codPais'";
            $resultado2 = mysqli_query($enlace, $consulta2);
            while($fila2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $fila2['Language'] ."'>" . $fila2['Language'] . "</option>";
            }
        } 
        if (isset($_POST['accion']) && $_POST['accion'] == "Buscar") {
            if (!$brellenar) {
                echo "Por favor, presiona primero el botón Rellenar.";
            } else {
                    $bbuscar = true;
                    $consulta2 = "SELECT Language FROM countrylanguage WHERE Countrycode='$codPais'";
                    $resultado2 = mysqli_query($enlace, $consulta2);
                    while ($fila2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2)) {
                    $selected = ($_POST['lang'] == $fila2['Language']) ? 'selected' : '';
                    echo "<option value='" . $fila2['Language'] . "' $selected>" . $fila2['Language'] . "</option>";
                    }
                     $lengua = $_POST['lang'];                                               
                    $consulta3 = "SELECT IsOfficial, Percentage FROM countrylanguage WHERE CountryCode = '$codPais' AND Language = '$lengua'";
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($enlace, $consulta3);
                    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
                    $oficial = $fila['IsOfficial'] == 'T' ? 'Si' : 'No';                    
                    $porcentaje = $fila['Percentage'];
            }    
        }     
        ?>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="accion" value="Rellenar">Rellenar Lenguas</button><br>
    <label><b>Es oficial</b></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ofic" value="Si" <?php echo $oficial == 'Si' ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
    <label for="Si"><b>Si</b></label>
    <input type="radio" name="ofic" value="No" <?php echo $oficial == 'No' ? 'checked' : ''; ?>> 
    <label for="No"><b>No</b></label> <br>
    <label for="Porc"><b>Porcentaje</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="Porc" value="<?php echo $porcentaje; ?>"><br><br> 

    <?php
   
    if (isset($_POST['accion']) && $_POST['accion'] == "Aceptar") {     
        if (!$bbuscar) {
            echo "Por favor, presiona primero el botón el Buscar";
        } else {    
 $codPais = $_POST['codp'];
            $lengua = $_POST['lang'];
            $porcentaje = $_POST['Porc'];
            $oficial = $_POST['ofic'] == 'Si' ? 'T' : 'F';
            $consulta4 = "UPDATE countrylanguage SET IsOfficial = '$oficial', 
            Percentage = '$porcentaje' WHERE CountryCode = '$codPais' AND Language = 
            '$lengua'";
            mysqli_query($enlace, $consulta4);
            echo "<br><br>";                                            
            echo "**Los cambios se han actualizado correctamente**";                                                        
           
        }
    }
    ?>
   
    <button type="submit" name="accion" value="Buscar">Buscar datos</button>
    <button type="submit" name="accion" value="Aceptar">Aceptar cambios</button>
    <a href="index.php">Volver al Menú</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tienes tres botones del tipo **submit** para un único formulario, lo que pretendes no se puede hacer solo con PHP a menos que vayas pasando entre formularios cada acción. Creo que necesitas meterle JS a eso o sino algo así: el primer form y botón te llevan al segundo form, el segundo form y botón te llevan al tercer y ultimo form y ahí estaría el ultimo botón que ya habría validado los otros...